# Почему выдает ошибку? - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

Вот исходный код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::string P, R;
    cin >> P >> R;
    vector<char> PMassive(P.begin(), P.end());
    vector<char> RMassive(R.begin(), R.end());
    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = R.length();
metka:
    int counter3 = P.length();
    if (counter2 == 0) goto end;
    if (PMassive[counter3] == RMassive[counter2]) {
        counter2--;
        counter3--;
    }
    else if (counter2 != 0) { counter++; goto metka; }
end:
    std::cout << counter;




    Sleep(5000);
    return 0;
}
```

Выдает ошибку vector subscript out of range: http://snap.ashampoo.com/biLxWrF4
Проблема в (PMassive[counter3] == RMassive[counter2]). Что мне сделать, чтобы ее исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При работе с контейнером `std::string P` вам разрешается обращаться к элементам с индексами в диапазоне `[ 0, P.length() ]`. Основное содержимое строки будет располагаться по индексам от `0` до `P.length() - 1`, а последний элемент - с индексом `P.length()` - будет вести себя как нулевой терминатор, следующий сразу за основным содержимым строки.

Однако этот нулевой терминатор не считается собственной частью строки и в диапазон итераторов `[ P.begin(), P.end() )` он не входит. Поэтому если вы решили скопировать содержимое строки в другой контейнер - вектор - через

```
vector<char> PMassive(P.begin(), P.end());
```

то в этом векторе `P` вам уже не разрешается доступаться к элементу с индексом `P.length()`. Такого элемента не существует. Разрешенные индексы для такого вектора лежат в диапазоне `[ 0, P.length() - 1 ]`.

Вы же обращаетесь в этот вектор по индексу `P.length()`, что и приводит к ошибке.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что массивы в C++ индексируются не от 1 до длины, а от 0 до (длины − 1).

А вы начинаете итерацию с индекса `P.length()`, который равен длине.